# cannot undo storyboard changes xcode

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Does anyone know how I can undo changes made to a storyboard. Everytime I accidentally delete an element I cannot get it back and it is becoming a real timewaster.

Anyone know?

Comment: are you using xcode 5?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do a simple undo from Xcode storyboard, it might be related to some leftovers...

To make a good cleanup:

1. open Xcode
2. clean product (Command + Shift + K)
3. Clean Build folder (Option + Command + Shift + K)
4. Close Xcode
5. delete /Users/(your username)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
6. repopen xcode
7. open Storyboard, change something,  try to use Command+Z

Hope it works

Comment: ill try it and let you know.

Comment: This solution is not working for me, is there any other ways ?

Comment: @Alex sorry that's all I've got :)

Comment: This is my problem actually. See if you can catch the bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27194237/unable-perform-undo-changes-in-storyboard-file-always-showing-undo-change-fram

Answer (score 1):

Using MAC + Z or Edit Menu -> Undo.

Comment: It is not the answer to my problem. Undo is greyed out. It is simply not saving previous states.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hit the delete key in storyboard. You'll wipe out the storyboard file. I dragged it from the macbook trash back into the xCode navigator. Good old trash.